"Exotic" examples of linear homomorphisms of $C^\infty(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$
Context: I am searching for examples of linear maps from the vector space $C^\infty(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$ of all smooth function $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ to itself. Even "exotic" ones.
So far: already known examples :

$f\mapsto \int_0^x f(t)\text{d}t$ (integration);
$f\mapsto \frac{\text{d}^nf}{\text{d}t^n}$ for all $n$ (derivation);
$f\mapsto f(\,\cdot\,-a)$ (translation);
every linear combination/composition of the examples stated above...

What I am trying to do: I am trying to show that a family of vector in $\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$ is linearly independent, and I was hoping to do it by showing that its elements were eigenvectors of an operator but for different eigenvalues. Example of such family would be $\{e^{ax},xe^{ax}\}$. I know this example can be solved with analytic methods, but it would be easier to generalize with the method I try to use.

What is your family of functions? That would help to know

I didn't want to give the precise family so that it wouldn't look like homework solving. Some of the elements are of the form $x\exp(ax)$ for example.

There are $2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$ many linear functions from $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ to itself, so without more context on what you’re using this linear map for, there’s really no way to answer this other than just saying there’re plenty more such linear maps than what you’ve written down.

@Kolakoski54 I understand you’re trying to avoid this being seen as homework question, but without more details on what you’re trying to do, this is just an overly vague and broad question with essentially no way to answer.

Thank for your comments. One introductory example would be to show that ${\exp(ax),x\exp(ax)}$ is linearly independent in $\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb R,\mathbb R)$ by showing that its elements are eigenvectors for the same operator, but for distinct eigenvalues (I know you can do it with analytic methods).

@Kolakoski54 I tried a few things. I don’t see any “natural” operator which satisfies your required condition, but I can’t say for sure. (An “exotic” one, of course, exists, but I can only prove its existence after showing the set is linearly independent, so it doesn’t help much.)

Thanks for trying @DavidGao!
